# LSTM predictions for time-series is both shifted and outputting wrong values

Tags: time-series, lstm, keras

I am currently trying to apply an LSTM to a time-series problem with hourly data. I have 10 features that represent weather data (time-dependent), and I want to predict a target vector of solar illumination values for 182 grid points in space, for each time step.

My issue is that the predicted values are not only shifted a few hours back, but the values are also off by quite a bit.

I tried to tackle the problem by:

1. Splitting the data into 70:15:15 train:val:test, normalising the features and taking the log1p of the target (without the log1p, values span 5 orders of magnitude and the frequency distribution is very right-skewed)
2. Using TimeseriesGenerator for single-timestep output, using either the previous-hour data or previous 24-hours data
3. Trained the model using a simple LSTM with 10 units, followed by a Dense layer with 182 output neurons
4. Predicting the values for the test set, and plotting the predicted vs actual values for the first few data points.

The code is reported below for the previous-hour data; the same issue exists for the 24-h case:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df_lstm_train = df_lstm[:int(0.7 * len(df_lstm))]
df_lstm_val = df_lstm[int(0.7 * len(df_lstm)):int(0.85 * len(df_lstm))]
df_lstm_test = df_lstm[int(0.85 * len(df_lstm)):]

train_data = df_lstm_train.iloc[:,:10].values
train_labels = np.log1p(df_lstm_train.iloc[:,10:].values)

val_data = df_lstm_val.iloc[:,:10].values
val_labels = np.log1p(df_lstm_val.iloc[:,10:].values)

test_data = df_lstm_test.iloc[:,:10].values
test_labels = np.log1p(df_lstm_test.iloc[:,10:].values)

scaler = StandardScaler()
train_data = scaler.fit_transform(train_data)
val_data = scaler.transform(val_data)
test_data = scaler.transform(test_data)

train_data_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(train_data, train_labels,
                               length=1, sampling_rate=1,
                               batch_size=1)

val_data_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(val_data, val_labels,
                               length=1, sampling_rate=1,
                               batch_size=1)

test_data_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(test_data, test_labels,
                               length=1, sampling_rate=1,
                               batch_size=1)


CELLS = 10

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = CELLS))
model.add(Dense(units = 182))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = [tfa.metrics.RSquare(y_shape=(182,))])

# ModelCheckpoint and EarlyStopping callbacks implemented (not reported in code)

history = model.fit(train_data_gen, epochs = 500, validation_data = val_data_gen, callbacks) # loss: 0.1176 - r_square: 0.9882 - val_loss: 0.3278 - val_r_square: 0.9663 by epoch 27

pred = model.predict(test_data_gen)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,3, figsize = (15,12)) # just plot the the first 9 grid points
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flatten()):
  ax.plot(pred_ill[:24,i], label = 'LSTM')
  ax.plot(np.log1p(train_labels[:24,i]),  label = 'Actual')
  if i == 0:
    ax.legend()
```

and this is the plot:

[image: LSTM predict vs actual illumination]

Any clues as to what I have done wrong and how I can try to solve it?